# System volume info folder creation

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

[This is what tree file size shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijjY.png)[This is the PowerShell screenshot that tells about the windows shadow copies[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjJYi.png)I have turned system protection off and manually make backups using the Windows 7 backup and restore option. I make the backup in D drive but the System Volume Information folder in drive E fills up automatically.

This does not happen with F drive though the backup that I make in D contains files from both of them. Then why is the sys vol info folder created and can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

No, don't delete it, you need to turn off the services using it. One of them is the file/search index system which is the problem most of the time (if you turned off backup etc.), others are [Windows Backup, System Image Backup, Volume Shadow Copy service, and Windows Search indexing

1. Keys Windows+R  (Run Command)
2. Command: control
3. Search Key [F3 ] + Enter : index
4. Select "Indexing Options"
5. Customize "Indexing Options"

Comment: The thing is that I have turned system protection off for the E drive so the restore points must not be there in the system volume information folder. As far as the indexing is concered, I had the E drive included in the windows index and have now removed it with only C drive and start inside it. I have also rebuilt the index, but no space has been freed.

Comment: @MayankVerma What about Backup and the other services? If you deactivated all, can you post screenshots of each setting in your answer? Maybe you got it wrong.

Comment: I  have edited my question and added 2 photos. See if this helps.